# Formatting text on sonoma

Tags: text

I just "upgraded" to Sonoma, and discovered it no longer handles postscript files. I have a simple script to format text files:

```
ENSCRIPT="--no-header --margins=36:36:36:36 --font=Courier12 --word-wrap --media=Letter"
export ENSCRIPT
/opt/local/bin/enscript -p - $1 | /usr/bin/lpr
```

that no longer works as a result and I was wondering if anyone knew of alternatives?

Comment: Isn't this a [brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/enscript) thing?

Comment: enscript may be, but that's working - lpr just complains it can't handle "application/postscript" now, so I'm looking for an alternative to enscript that will generate something lpr will like